# acm two column format, second column colliding with title

Tags: two-column, acmart

Im a beginner in LaTeX, trying to write a document in acm two column format.
In the first page, the second column collides with the title:

[image: Second column colliding with title]

I found some code about changing the column start with

> \vspace{1cm}

Or similars but it didnt help. Also, i figure the template would probably deal with that automatically(?)

What am i doing wrong?

Here is my LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass[acmlarge, twocolumn]{acmart}
\usepackage{lipsum}


%opening
\title{My big and fancy title: wow, much information but still concise. So beautiful.}
\author{Marco A. B Montevechi Filho}
\settopmatter{printacmref=false}
\settopmatter{printfolios=false}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@formatdoi[1]{\ignorespaces}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{abstract}
        
        \textbf{Abstract:} \lipsum[10]
        
    \end{abstract}
    
    \maketitle
    
    \section{Introduction}
    \subsection{Overview}
    
    \lipsum[10-100]
    
    \subsection{Subsection}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Searching in overleaf i changed the documentclass to \documentclass[acmtog]{acmart} and it kinda worked... but why wouldnt the first line work out of the bat?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a two-column document, you can choose between the `acmtog`, `acmengage`, `sigconf`, or `sigplan` format.

(`\twocolumn` is not part of the allowed options of the class.)

`acmlarge` produces a single column document.

For example using `sigplan`

[image: a]

```
%\documentclass[acmtog]{acmart}

%\documentclass[acmengage]{acmart}

%\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

\documentclass[sigplan]{acmart}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \title{My big and fancy title: wow, much information but still concise. So beautiful.}
    \author{Marco A. B Montevechi Filho}
    \begin{abstract}
        
        \textbf{Abstract:} \lipsum[10]
        
    \end{abstract}
    
    \maketitle
    
    \section{Introduction}
    \subsection{Overview}
    
    \lipsum[10-100]
    
    \subsection{Subsection}
    
\end{document}
```

(Put `\title` and `\author` after `\begin{document}`. They are part of the top matter of the article)